# How do you DataBind a SqlDataSource to a DetailView in a UserControl?

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, user-controls, sqldatasource

I have a user control I have created that contains a details-view that I plan to use as a template to develop many other pages using.  For example, I want to use this control on another .aspx page I have.  This aspx page will use a SqlDataSource to databind to.  I am very new to this stuff so my understanding is limited, so be patient with me (thanks).

This is the basics of the user control:

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DV1" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" 
DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Height="16px" Width="100%" 
Font-Size="14pt" FooterText=" " ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" 
HeaderText=" ">
```

In the back code, I have made this ID accessible:

```
public DetailsView DetailView
    {
        get { return DV1; }
        set { DV1 = value; }
    }
```

In my aspx page I have:

```
<%@ Register Src="StdDetails_View.ascx" TagName="UserList" TagPrefix="uc" %>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ucsConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="usp_UserInfo_GetBy_ID" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="5afadb8a-3127-4a67-85dd-bde4de6d03c4" Name="ID" 
            Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

The only way I can get this to work is if I add BoundFields in the userControl to the specific stored-procedure I use.  Outside of this, I do not know what to do!  How do I go about binding this datasource using this detailview?

All your help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting AutoGenerateRows = true

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DV1" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="true" 
DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Height="16px" Width="100%" 
Font-Size="14pt" FooterText=" " ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" 
HeaderText=" ">
```

Comment: This ultimately solved the problem.  Minor bumps on the road still, but we're good! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The DataSourceID will only work within the same context (i.e. the usercontrol).  You will need to do something like this within the code-behind of your web form:

`UserList.DetailView.DataSource = SqlDataSource1`

Comment: This solved the problem.  I used DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1", however, i'm pretty sure they do the same thing.  Thanks!